# android string-array items with names

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a string-array in a resource file with a few items in the array. I know how to call the array by name. What I want is to be able to call the array item by a name. The resource file allows me to give the item a name 'item 1. How can I call this item by the given name something like this in my Java class

```
String[]array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
String item1 = array["item1"];
String item2 = array["item2"];
String item3 = array["item3"];
```

and in the resources the array looking like

```
<string-array name="myarray">
    <item name="item1">item 1</item>
    <item name="item2">item 2</item>
    <item name="item3">item </item>
 </string-array>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionary in android resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371942/dictionary-in-android-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hash, so you set the key and the value, see more on [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

> There is no such a resource type. You have to put an arbitrary file in res/raw/ and import it manually in a HashMap.

Posted here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371942/dictionary-in-android-resources)

To open these resources with a raw InputStream,  More [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)`

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to be able to call the array item by a name. The resource file allows me to give the item a name 'item 1.

Android Studio may allow you to use the `name` attribute, but items in a `<string-array>` resource do not support this attribute.

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray):

> ```
> <item>
> ```
>
> A string, which can include styling tags. The value can be a reference to another string resource. Must be a child of a `<string-array>` element. Beware that you must escape apostrophes and quotation marks. See Formatting and Styling, below, for information about to properly style and format your strings.
>
> No attributes.